# Picture editor in Android

Tags: android, image-processing, android-emulator

I am quite new to Android development and I wish like to develop my first app which is a picture editor.

Basically it can let the user adjust the brightness, contrast, black and white effects.

I would like to ask which package should I look for? I have roughly go through the Android API and I couldn't found any related packages.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

[Android - Bitmap set contrast and brightness](http://android.okhelp.cz/bitmap-set-contrast-and-brightness-android/)

You can set Contrast on bitmap using this:

```
private static void setContrastScaleOnly(ColorMatrix cm, float contrast) {
    float scale = contrast + 1.f;
    float translate = (-.5f * scale + .5f) * 255.f;
        cm.set(new float[] {
               scale, 0, 0, 0, 0,
               0, scale, 0, 0, 0,
               0, 0, scale, 0, 0,
               0, 0, 0, 1, 0 });
}
private static void setContrast(ColorMatrix cm, float contrast) {
    float scale = contrast + 1.f;
    float translate = (-.5f * scale + .5f) * 255.f;
        cm.set(new float[] {
               scale, 0, 0, 0, translate,
               0, scale, 0, 0, translate,
               0, 0, scale, 0, translate,
               0, 0, 0, 1, 0 });
}

private static void setContrastTranslateOnly(ColorMatrix cm, float contrast) {
    float scale = contrast + 1.f;
    float translate = (-.5f * scale + .5f) * 255.f;
        cm.set(new float[] {
               1, 0, 0, 0, translate,
               0, 1, 0, 0, translate,
               0, 0, 1, 0, translate,
               0, 0, 0, 1, 0 });
}
```

In your `onDraw` call this methods with your params to set contrast and brightness.

Hope ti helps.

Answer (score 0):

The place to start looking in the android doc would be the [2D Graphics section](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html) in particular the [BitmapDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html) or [PictureDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/PictureDrawable.html) which display [Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) and [Picture](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Picture.html). It will be up to you (or other 3rd party image manipulation libraries) to build up either a Picture or a Bitmap in memory, modify it, then use the *Drawable to write to the screen.